# 2 questions regarding static files and templates/web interface in django

Tags: python, django

First off when I am trying to get my CSS going on my local laptop server I can seem to get the right code to get the CSS to load. I've gotten a 404 in the command prompt whenever it tries to load. The code that I'm currnelty using is `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}mycss.css" />`


the second question I have is if there is a way to link to certain pages with a variable for the site name. So say i was coding a logout button. Instead of having `<href="yoursite.com/logout">` I could have something like `<href="{{sitename}}logout}}>` or something along those lines.

Comment: 404 - for straight forward error  you dont have to ask in SO .

Comment: huh? what do you mean I dont have to ask in SO? I'm asking if that code is correct and that's why I'm getting a 404?

Comment: code is not correct thats why 404 . and ..there was no code before !

Comment: do you know what about the code is in correct? thus why I'm posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: have you told the django development server to serve the static media for you? [See the docs on how to set this up](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/?from=olddocs#serving-static-files-in-development)

Regarding the second question: I'm not sure why you would need to do this as all your links can just be `<a href="/logout">` i.e. relative to your url but yes, you can use [django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) to accomplish this.

Comment: well it would just be easier to do this to test in the local server and then not have to change anything once i get to actually deploying it. but yeah.